# mvc - get image from database and display to details view

Tags: c#, sql, image, model-view-controller, byte

**model:**

```
public byte[] TECH_IMAGE { get; set; }
```

**controller:**

```
//DETAILS
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            tblTechDeployment tech = db.tblTechDeployments.Find(id);

        if (tech == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        return View(tech);

        var i = db.tblTechDeployments.Find(id);
        var vm = new tblTechDeployment
        {
            TECH_IMAGE = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(i.TECH_IMAGE)
        };

        //var image = (from i in db.tblTechDeployments
        //             select i.TECH_IMAGE).FirstOrDefault();
        //var stream = new MemoryStream(image.ToArray());
        //return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

**details view:**

```
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TECH_IMAGE)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @*@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TECH_IMAGE)*@<img     src="@Model.TECH_IMAGE" />
    </dd>
```

I've an mvc project which displays all the technicians with the details button which when click it will display all the information of techs coming from the database. i'm getting it all correctly except for the image.

the image data type in the database is image. and it displays the data as

```
0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4948445200000258000000.......................(it's so long...)..........
```

it looks also like that in the details view.

the 4 lines that are comment out in the controller is the another way i found in the net. but i can't get it to work. or am i doing it incorrectly?

also this code:

```
var i = db.tblTechDeployments.Find(id);
    var vm = new tblTechDeployment
    {
        TECH_IMAGE = "data:image/png;base64," +     Convert.ToBase64String(i.TECH_IMAGE)
    };
```

i'm getting error:

> cannot implicitly convert type string to byte.

how can i display the image stored in the database to details view?

Comment: `TECH_IMAGE` property is a byte array, and you're trying to add image metadata on Base64 format into it. Instead of re-assign byte array, try to provide a string property as target assignment, e.g.: `var vm = new tblTechDeployment { Image = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(i.TECH_IMAGE) };`

Comment: You just need to add new property type of string and assign that property to view.You can use viewbag or viewdata too.